# Resouces tab missing in Blend For Visual Studio 2019

Tags: xaml, tabs, resources, blend

On past versions of Blend For Visual Studio, I used to edit Styles and Templates from Resource Dictionaries under the "Resource" tab, usually on right side of the screen.

On last updates off Visual Studio 2019, this tab disappeared. Had it been removed?

[image: s]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `Resources` tab will appear only if you open `App.xaml` file.

Then you can open another `xaml` file and `Resources` tab will be there until you close all tabs.

It's either a bug or really weird behavior.

[image]

Comment: Not for me. Also, there is no resources tab at all. https://i.imgur.com/EqAyEEw.png
Which version do you have? I have 16.9.4, which is up to date.

Comment: I have the same version, 16.9.4.

Comment: If I select app.xaml file in the solution explorer then there is Resources item in View menu.

Comment: Thanks for help. It can be a problem if the XAMLs to be edited are under a class library.